# How do I combine storage in a Windows tablet between internal storage and Micro SD card?

Tags: windows, windows-10, storage, sd-card

I have a tablet running Windows 10 Pro Creator's Update  that has 128GB of internal storage. The operating system at most should take up 80GB. It also has a Micro SD slot which I inserted a 256GB micro SD card. How do I best combine the storage between the remaining internal storage and micro sd card?

Answer (score 2):

The main way of combining storage in Windows 10 is using Storage Spaces. Generally speaking, using Powershell cmdlets is better than using the GUI as it offers better control over how the Storage Space is created.

First of all, resize the partitions so that the internal storage has an unused partition holding the space you would like to include in the combined storage.

Next, create a VHD in the micro-sd card and mount the VHD. You can set it to automount on start up using scheduled tasks.

If the internal storage is faster than the micro sd card (run speed tests to verify), you can set up tiered storage for this using the below commands where you need to customise the parts pre and suffixed with xx for your own names. You will also need to adjust the `TierSize` adjustments.

```
$PhysicalDisks = (Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $True)
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName xxStoragePoolxx -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage on xxStoragexx" -PhysicalDisks $PhysicalDisks
Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "Msft Virtual Disk" -MediaType HDD
Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "VID:45 SEM128" -MediaType SSD

Get-StoragePool xxStoragePoolxx | New-StorageTier -FriendlyName SSD-tier -MediaType SSD -ResiliencySettingName Simple
Get-StoragePool xxStoragePoolxx | New-StorageTier -FriendlyName HDD-tier -MediaType HDD -ResiliencySettingName Simple
Get-StoragePool xxStoragePoolxx | Set-ResiliencySetting -Name Simple -NumberOfColumnsDefault 1
$SSD = Get-StorageTier -FriendlyName SSD-tier
$HDD = Get-StorageTier -FriendlyName HDD-tier
$SSDTiersize = Get-StorageTierSupportedSize SSD-tier -ResiliencySettingName Simple | select -ExpandProperty TierSizeMax
$HDDTiersize = Get-StorageTierSupportedSize HDD-tier -ResiliencySettingName Simple | select -ExpandProperty TierSizeMax
$SSDTiersize -= 4GB
$HDDTiersize -= 2GB
New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName  xxStoragePoolxx -FriendlyName xxStorageNamexx -ResiliencySettingName Simple -StorageTiers $SSD, $HDD -StorageTierSizes $SSDTiersize, $HDDTiersize -WriteCacheSize 5GB

Get-StoragePool xxStoragePoolxx | Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort Size | FT FriendlyName, Size, MediaType, HealthStatus, OperationalStatus -AutoSize
```